Need to display 0 with Column value name if the column value in 0 or null in snowflake
ex - I have  a column called column1. It has multiple values, like 15 or more values in it. I need to pick only four values (AAA,BBB,CCC,DDD alone) in that for my calculation. These four values may be null or 0 and, due to that, I get the sum of these as 0 or null.
I need to display all the four values in the query output if the sum is 0 or more  ans independent row. If the sum is 0 then it should show 0 in the count column.
Further, I need to rename the Column values and group them into a single value.Since, there might be other values which contain these values in a different format.
My query :Sample code for understanding
select ADD_MONTHS(LAST_DAY(select  date  from cw.cw_cs.cw_vw_cw_us_date),-1) AS Date,
'MT09' as "ID",
'Number of Asset' as "Name",
(case when Entity Like'%AAA%' then 'AAA'
         when Entity like '%BBB%' then 'Sol-BBB'
        when Entity like '%CCC%' then 'MU-CCC'
         when Entity = 'DDD' then 'MU-DDD'
         else 'Others' end ) as "Entity",
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN SEVERITY_ID='X' THEN CMDBHASH_ASSET_CVE_COMBINE END)  as Numerator
FROM  cw.cw_cns.CW_VW_MS_VN_SU_HIS
group by "Entity"

output received:
DATE        Metric ID   Metric Name Legal Entity    NUMERATOR
7/31/2024   MT09    Number of Asset   MU-CCC    5
7/31/2024   MT09    Number of Asset   Others    0

My need :
DATE    Metric ID   Metric Name Legal Entity    NUMERATOR
7/31/2024   MT09    Number of Asset AAA          0
7/31/2024   MT09    Number of Asset MU-CCC           5
7/31/2024   MT09    Number of Asset Sol-BBB          0
7/31/2024   MT09    Number of Asset MU-DDD           0
7/31/2024   MT09    Number of Asset Others           2

Can someone please help me to achieve this.

can you add a sample data to produce the result you need?

CVE_APP_NM ENTITY ENVIRONMENT SUPPORT_GROUP_NM ASSET_STATUS
Other CAT-DDD   Installed
Other UNKNOWN UNKNOWN UNKNOWN UNKNOWN
Microsoft UNKNOWN  Support Center Installed
Other CCC- MT UNKNOWN UNKNOWN UNKNOWN
Other CCC UNKNOWN UNKNOWN UNKNOWN
Git UNKNOWN   Absent
Apache UNKNOWN UNKNOWN UNKNOWN UNKNOWN
Cisco UNKNOWN UNKNOWN UNKNOWN UNKNOWN
Other UNKNOWN UNKNOWN UNKNOWN UNKNOWN
Microsoft AAA Production VDI Services Installed

Added the sample data . Sorry but the format is changing when i paste here .

You can try this may be
-Generate all required entities with zero counts using a CTE.
-Perform a LEFT JOIN between this CTE and the actual aggregated data to ensure all specified entities are included in the final output.
I don't have a sample dataset to test, but you can try the below query:
Example:
    WITH RequiredEntities AS (
    SELECT 'AAA' AS Entity
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Sol-BBB'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'MU-CCC'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'MU-DDD'
),
AggregatedData AS (
    SELECT 
        ADD_MONTHS(LAST_DAY(date), -1) AS Date,
        'MT09' AS "Metric ID",
        'Number of Asset' AS "Metric Name",
        CASE 
            WHEN Entity LIKE '%AAA%' THEN 'AAA'
            WHEN Entity LIKE '%BBB%' THEN 'Sol-BBB'
            WHEN Entity LIKE '%CCC%' THEN 'MU-CCC'
            WHEN Entity = 'DDD' THEN 'MU-DDD'
            ELSE 'Others'
        END AS "Legal Entity",
        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN SEVERITY_ID='X' THEN CMDBHASH_ASSET_CVE_COMBINE END) AS Numerator
    FROM cw.cw_cns.CW_VW_MS_VN_SU_HIS
    GROUP BY 
        CASE 
            WHEN Entity LIKE '%AAA%' THEN 'AAA'
            WHEN Entity LIKE '%BBB%' THEN 'Sol-BBB'
            WHEN Entity LIKE '%CCC%' THEN 'MU-CCC'
            WHEN Entity = 'DDD' THEN 'MU-DDD'
            ELSE 'Others'
        END
)
SELECT 
    ADD_MONTHS(LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE), -1) AS Date, 
    'MT09' AS "Metric ID", 
    'Number of Asset' AS "Metric Name", 
    RE.Entity AS "Legal Entity", 
    COALESCE(A.Numerator, 0) AS Numerator
FROM RequiredEntities RE
LEFT JOIN AggregatedData A ON RE.Entity = A."Legal Entity"
UNION
SELECT 
    ADD_MONTHS(LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE), -1) AS Date, 
    'MT09' AS "Metric ID", 
    'Number of Asset' AS "Metric Name", 
    "Legal Entity", 
    Numerator
FROM AggregatedData
WHERE "Legal Entity" NOT IN ('AAA', 'Sol-BBB', 'MU-CCC', 'MU-DDD')
ORDER BY 
    "Legal Entity";


It works perfectly as per my ask .Thank you Asim Rout !!
I have one additional requirement like denominator for all entities which will be distinct total count of each entities. This is for calculating percentage

As per your recent ask in the comment
I have one additional requirement like denominator for all entities which will be distinct total count of each entities. This is for calculating percentage
, you can use the below code:
WITH RequiredEntities AS (
    SELECT 'AAA' AS Entity
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Sol-BBB'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'MU-CCC'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'MU-DDD'
),
AggregatedData AS (
    SELECT 
        ADD_MONTHS(LAST_DAY(date), -1) AS Date,
        'MT09' AS "Metric ID",
        'Number of Asset' AS "Metric Name",
        CASE 
            WHEN Entity LIKE '%AAA%' THEN 'AAA'
            WHEN Entity LIKE '%BBB%' THEN 'Sol-BBB'
            WHEN Entity LIKE '%CCC%' THEN 'MU-CCC'
            WHEN Entity = 'DDD' THEN 'MU-DDD'
            ELSE 'Others'
        END AS "Legal Entity",
        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN SEVERITY_ID='X' THEN CMDBHASH_ASSET_CVE_COMBINE END) AS Numerator,
        COUNT(DISTINCT CMDBHASH_ASSET_CVE_COMBINE) AS Denominator  -- Calculate Denominator
    FROM cw.cw_cns.CW_VW_MS_VN_SU_HIS
    GROUP BY 
        CASE 
            WHEN Entity LIKE '%AAA%' THEN 'AAA'
            WHEN Entity LIKE '%BBB%' THEN 'Sol-BBB'
            WHEN Entity LIKE '%CCC%' THEN 'MU-CCC'
            WHEN Entity = 'DDD' THEN 'MU-DDD'
            ELSE 'Others'
        END
)
SELECT 
    ADD_MONTHS(LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE), -1) AS Date, 
    'MT09' AS "Metric ID", 
    'Number of Asset' AS "Metric Name", 
    RE.Entity AS "Legal Entity", 
    COALESCE(A.Numerator, 0) AS Numerator,
    COALESCE(A.Denominator, 0) AS Denominator,
    CASE 
        WHEN COALESCE(A.Denominator, 0) > 0 THEN ROUND((COALESCE(A.Numerator, 0) / COALESCE(A.Denominator, 0)) * 100, 2)
        ELSE 0
    END AS Percentage
FROM RequiredEntities RE
LEFT JOIN AggregatedData A ON RE.Entity = A."Legal Entity"
UNION
SELECT 
    ADD_MONTHS(LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE), -1) AS Date, 
    'MT09' AS "Metric ID", 
    'Number of Asset' AS "Metric Name", 
    "Legal Entity", 
    Numerator,
    Denominator,
    CASE 
        WHEN Denominator > 0 THEN ROUND((Numerator / Denominator) * 100, 2)
        ELSE 0
    END AS Percentage
FROM AggregatedData
WHERE "Legal Entity" NOT IN ('AAA', 'Sol-BBB', 'MU-CCC', 'MU-DDD')
ORDER BY 
    "Legal Entity";

